# mongoose generating a children field using parent field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a family tree website using mongodb. upon creating a new family member, i only want to reference the parent (father) of the person and have mongoose automatically generate a children field in the person model. Here is the Person schema:

```
Person.add({
    fullName: { type: String, initial:true, required: true,label: , index:true,  },
    parent: {type: Types.Relationship, ref:'Person'},
});
```

As you can see, upon creating a new person, I would want mongoose to automatically find all people in the Person model with the parent id matching the person I'm creating and generate an array of ids in the children field.

I have done some researches and found that Mongoose Virtuals can provide something like that but i have not found any documentation regarding querying the model to add to the virtual field. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `post save` hook in your `Person` schema model, and then `find` the people with parent id and `create/update` children array of that person.

use `$addToSet` instead of `$push` so that same childrens are not pushed more than once.

Try this:

```
PersonSchema.post('save', function(doc, next) {
    this.findOneAndUpdate({_id : doc.parent},{$addToSet : { children : doc._id}})
    next();
});
```

Read more about [mongoose hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post) for detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I think your solution is on the right way but i got a ` MongoError: Unknown modifier: $addtoSet `. Do you have any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: I have updated the answer, it should be addToSet with capital "T" and also it takes an object ( not a value),I have updated that as well. Use the latest code

Comment: thanks! since I'm using keystone js with the children field is a keystone relationship type so i have to pass the whole doc `{$addToSet : { children : doc}}` but i worked nonetheless : )